# Can I dual boot Ubuntu and Windows to run both operating systems simultaneously?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I'm a new forum user and new to Linux.

I have 2 1TB HDDs in an older Dell Optiplex 790.  Windows 10 Pro currently boots from hdd0.

I also have multiple displays: one from the VGA port (display 1) and the other from the DisplayPort (display 2).

**What I'd like to do is install Ubuntu on hdd1, BUT have both Windows and Ubuntu boot at the same time, with Windows on hdd0 on display 1 and Ubuntu on hdd1 on display 2.**

Is this possible? If so, can you explain how to do it?  I am new to using Linux.

Comment: No, you can't run things that way. However, you can create a virtual Ubuntu installation using **VirtualBox** under Windows, and then you **can** run both at the same time. See https://www.virtualbox.org/ or go to the Windows app store.

Comment: If you want to run Ubuntu and Windows simultaneously, install VirtualBox on one or the other. Then, if you have an ISO image for the one without VirtualBox, you can *technically* run them simultaneously. That's basically what @heynnema said.

Answer (score 3):

Dual-boot simply won't get you there. A computer operating system expects to have complete control over hardware -- they are not designed to share. You cannot dual-boot two OS simultaneously.

The only way to have multiple OS run simultaneously is for one to be a Virtual Machine (VM) Host and the others to be VM Guests.

- Allocation of HDD and displays and resources is done by the Host OS, and the simplest way is to use the settings in the Host VM application.
- You DON'T need a separate disk, because the VM application will create a Virtual HDD for each Guest, housed in a file on the Host.

Advice: Install a VM Application on your current OS.

Comment: Thanks for that advice. I will use it.  Now my question is, even if I don't need a second drive, I have one being shipped to me as we speak.  I would be able to use that 2nd drive as a guest (or part of it) and install ubuntu on that, correct?  Thanks, JP

Comment: No. See the second bullet point. Both HDDs belong to the Host OS. If you want a disk-Virtual Drive for Ubuntu that happens to be located on that second drive, that's entirely your choice...but that design limits you needlessly. Advice: Stick to the VM Application defaults and the Ubuntu defaults until you have some experience. Consider using that second HDD for backups.

Comment: Copy that.  Hey, you guys are the experts here and I'm the newbie (FNG).  I will follow your advice and I appreciate it too.

Comment: One more question about this.  About how much space should be required when I create the virtual guest for Ubuntu?

Comment: The VM application will handle that for you. Expect 25-40GB. It's a file on the host, not a partition, not a drive. The file can use more space if it needs. If you don't have enough space on the Host, then stop. Fix that problem first.

Comment: oh, ok.  before i download virtualbox, have you had any experience with Microsoft's Hyper-V?  it's built in to windows 10 pro.

Comment: Not me. Others do.